# Problema al intentar subir productos en woocommerce desde php

Tags: php, api, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy intentando a traves de esta api https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/ obtener los productos y subirlos a woocommerce, el problema es que al usar este metodo GET/product/{id}/{storeCode} para crear los atributos si hay elemntos iguales solo se queda ultimo elemento guardado, ejemplo hay una opcion llamada qty, esta me llega desde la api varias opciones pero a la hora de crear el atributo solo se queda la ultima opción, les dejo el código para ver que podría agregar para evitar este problema

```
// Recorremos el array de productos
    foreach($products[0] as $product):
//         if($limit <= 4):

            // Creamos variables para los datos de los productos
            $product_id = $product->id;
            $product_title = ucwords($product->name);
            $product_slug = sanitize_title($product_title);
            $product_sku = $product->sku;
            $product_category = $product->category;
            $product_enabled = $product->enabled;

          // Comprobaremos si el producto ya existe
//             $existing_product = get_page_by_path( $product_slug, 'OBJECT', 'product' );

//             if($existing_product === null){

                // Creamos el producto
                $inserProduct = new WC_Product_Variable();

                $inserProduct->set_name( $product_title ); // product title
    
                // Comprobamos si la categoria ya existe
                $exists_category = term_exists( $product_category );

                //Si no existe la crea y la asigna
                if (!$exists_category) {
                    //Creamos la categoria primero antes de asignarla
                    $category = wp_insert_term(
                        $product_category,   // the term 
                        'product_cat'
                    );

                    $inserProduct->set_category_ids( array( $category['term_id'] ) );
                }else{
                    $inserProduct->set_category_ids( array( $exists_category ) );
                }

                $inserProduct->set_sku( $product_sku );
    
                // Creamos array para guardar los atributos de los productos
                $attributes = array();

                // Hacemos la llamda a la api para obtener los atributos
                $atributes_api = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/product/' . $product_id . '/us', $args));
                $atributes_api = json_decode( $atributes_api );
    
                // Hacemos la llamda a la api para obtener los atributos
                foreach($atributes_api[0] as $atributeAPI):

                    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                    $attribute->set_name( $atributeAPI->group );
                    $attribute->set_options( array($atributeAPI->name) );
                    $attribute->set_visible( true );
                    $attribute->set_variation( true );
                    $attributes[] = $attribute;
                endforeach;
    
                $inserProduct->set_attributes( $attributes );
                
                $inserProduct->save();
                die();
//             }
//         endif;
        $limit++;
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás enfrentando es que estás sobrescribiendo los atributos en lugar de agregarlos a un **array existente**. Para solucionar este problema, puedes modificar el código dentro del bucle `foreach` de los atributos para verificar si el atributo ya existe en el array `$attributes`. Si existe, simplemente agregas la opción al atributo existente, de lo contrario, **creas un nuevo atributo**. Aquí tienes el código modificado:

```php
// ...
// Hacemos la llamda a la api para obtener los atributos
foreach($atributes_api[0] as $atributeAPI):
    // Verifica si el atributo ya existe en el array $attributes
    $existing_attribute = null;
    foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
        if ($attr->get_name() == $atributeAPI->group) {
            $existing_attribute = $attr;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Si el atributo existe, agrega la opción al atributo existente
    if ($existing_attribute !== null) {
        $existing_options = $existing_attribute->get_options();
        $existing_options[] = $atributeAPI->name;
        $existing_attribute->set_options($existing_options);
    } else {
        // Crea un nuevo atributo y agrégalo al array $attributes
        $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
        $attribute->set_name($atributeAPI->group);
        $attribute->set_options(array($atributeAPI->name));
        $attribute->set_visible(true);
        $attribute->set_variation(true);
        $attributes[] = $attribute;
    }
endforeach;
// ...
```

Espero que este código te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: Si estaba intentando hacer algo asi pero no se me ocurria como, voy a probar esto tiene buena pinta

Comment: A tu disposición quedo.

Comment: Amigo funciono muchas gracias

Comment: De nada! Recuerda marcar la pregunta como respondida!

Comment: Si cuando me deje la marco

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Amigo estoy intentando armar diferentes conjunto de id de estos atributos, pero el mismo problema que aqui, la idea seria poder armar todas las variantes posibles en un array con id, se te ocurre algo?

Comment: Lo podrías plasmar en otra pregunta así te puedo ayudar mejor? Así se facilita la respuesta y no lo dejamos en los comentarios

Comment: Ok dejame ver como planteo la pregunta, lo que pasa es que aqui son muy quisquillosos con el armado de preguntas

Comment: Sí, pero no puedo responder tu pregunta por los comentarios ya que son pocos los caracteres que me deja ingresar...

Comment: Claro entiendo, armo la pregunta y te paso link

Comment: Genial! A tu disposición

Comment: aqui esta la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588390/quiero-armar-un-key-con-los-ids-de-los-atributos-de-un-producto

Comment: Genial! La estoy revisando!

Comment: Ok gracias, ahi edite un poco el codigo