# Quiero armar un key con los ids de los atributos de un producto

Tags: php, api, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito armar una variable con que contenga un string asi "5-140-447-448", esta variable tiene que contener los ids de atributos que me llegan a través de la api:

```
{
            "id": 4,
            "group": "size",
            "name": "3.5 x 2",
            "hidden": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "group": "qty",
            "name": "50",
            "hidden": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "group": "qty",
            "name": "75",
            "hidden": 0
        }
```

El problema como pueden ver es que atributos como qty las diferentes opciones me las pone por separado, la idea de ese key es armarlo con id de diferentes atributos (qty, size, Bundling, Scoring, etc), yo con este key luego lo mando a la api y recibo el precio de una variante, entonces la idea seria armar un key asi y un array con lso nombres de los atributos de los ids del key

```
                // Hacemos la llamda a la api para obtener los atributos
                $atributes_api = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/product/' . $product_id . '/us', $args));
                $atributes_api = json_decode( $atributes_api );
    
                // Tambien vamos a crear un array de opciones para cuando vayamos a enviar la llamada POST
                $productOptionsIds = array();
    
                // Recorremos el array obtenido en la llamada a la api
                foreach($atributes_api[0] as $atributeAPI):
    
                    $productOptionsIds[] = $atributeAPI->id;
    
                    // Verifica si el atributo ya existe en el array $attributes
                    $existing_attribute = null;
                    foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
                        if ($attr->get_name() == $atributeAPI->group) {
                            $existing_attribute = $attr;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Si el atributo existe, agrega la opción al atributo existente
                    if ($existing_attribute !== null) {
                        $existing_options = $existing_attribute->get_options();
                        $existing_options[] = $atributeAPI->name;
                        $existing_attribute->set_options($existing_options);
                    } else {
                        // Crea un nuevo atributo y agrégalo al array $attributes
                        $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
                        $attribute->set_name($atributeAPI->group);
                        $attribute->set_options(array($atributeAPI->name));
                        $attribute->set_visible(true);
                        $attribute->set_variation(true);
                        $attributes[] = $attribute;
                    }
                endforeach;
                
                // Aisgnamos los atributos al producto
                $inserProduct->set_attributes( $attributes );
                
                $key = array();
                    
                // Hacemos una llamada para obtener las diferentes variantes que tiene el producto
                $variant_api = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://api.sinaliteuppy.com/variants/' . $product_id . '/150', $args));
                $variant_api = json_decode( $variant_api );
    
                echo "<prev>";
                var_dump($variant_api);
                echo "</prev>";
                die();
                // Recorremos el array obtenido en la llamada a la api
                foreach($variant_api[0] as $variant):
    
//                  $productOptionsIds[] = $atributeAPI->id;
    
//                  // Verifica si el atributo ya existe en el array $attributes
//                  $existing_attribute = null;
//                  foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
//                      if ($attr->get_name() == $atributeAPI->group) {
//                          $existing_attribute = $attr;
//                          break;
//                      }
//                  }

//                  // Si el atributo existe, agrega la opción al atributo existente
//                  if ($existing_attribute !== null) {
//                      $existing_options = $existing_attribute->get_options();
//                      $existing_options[] = $atributeAPI->name;
//                      $existing_attribute->set_options($existing_options);
//                  } else {
//                      // Crea un nuevo atributo y agrégalo al array $attributes
//                      $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
//                      $attribute->set_name($atributeAPI->group);
//                      $attribute->set_options(array($atributeAPI->name));
//                      $attribute->set_visible(true);
//                      $attribute->set_variation(true);
//                      $attributes[] = $attribute;
//                  }
                endforeach;
```

Comment: Hola Felix! Todavía no termino de entender del todo lo que querés hacer. Hay alguna forma de que lo puedas explicar de otra forma?

Comment: SI ya mejoro la pregunta

Comment: Ya mejore la pregunta, revisa si asi la entiendes mejor